# How to change the language in LocaleManager without recreating the activity?

Tags: android, locale

An application has support of two languages, when i change the language then i must have to recreate the activity to show to desired result but i don't want to do it.

```
private void setNewLocale(AppCompatActivity mContext, @LocaleManager.LocaleDef String language) {
        LocaleManager.setNewLocale(this, language);
        Intent intent = mContext.getIntent();
        startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
```

Also i set the text again on All textfield but it didn't help!

When i am on the third activity of app and i change the language when i get back to second activity the text on second and first activity if i want to then i have to recreate those activity as well which i think is bad approach to do it.
I only want to change language but didn't want to recreate the activity!

On Button Click, i set the Locale!

```
if(appPreference.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("en")){
                    setNewLocale(MainActivity.this, LocaleManager.ARABIC);
                }
                else
                    setNewLocale(MainActivity.this, LocaleManager.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the appropriate way of changing the locale of the application:**
There are some difficulties which you have to overcome to change the language programmatically.

- Your application will not remember your language change after it is
  closed or recreated during the configuration change.
- You should update currently visible UI properly according to the
  selected language.

**Solution:**

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

For full description of process: [Link](https://medium.com/@gunhan/change-language-programmatically-in-android-69d4756c7d79)

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code which will update the screen without restarting or recreating activity again**

```
private void setNewLocale(AppCompatActivity mContext, @LocaleManager.LocaleDef String language) {
    val newConfig = baseContext.resources.configuration
    newConfig.setLocale(Locale(language))
    onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
}

override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    updateLabels()
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
}

private fun updateLabels() {
    //update all the views text here
    editTextMobileNumber.hint = getString(R.string.login_mobile_number_edit_text_hint)
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the correct language string here (    newConfig.setLocale(Locale(language))
)?
try "en" & "gu" in place of language and check it should work
like this newConfig.setLocale(Locale("gu"))

Comment: yes i pass the language correctly but it didn't change, this code only work when i recreate the activity!!